# How to manipulate checkbox state from parent (via props) and inside children component (state management in vue components)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, checkbox, vue-props, vue-reactivity

Every time I need to build a filter in vue, I run into the same problem.

I have an overall filter state which I currently manage in a composable. (In the old days it was vuex).

The filter includes checkboxes and can load an initial state from URL parameters. Passing the filter state down to the checkboxes initially is no problem. I do this with props.

From then the states are sometimes disconnected. Because if I click on the checkbox I have a local state change, the prop is still the same though.

I can, nonetheless change the parents state, which should be reflected in the child. For example with a `Filter reset` button, that unchecks all checkboxes.

Depending on what the childs state is, passing down that updated state is even reflected in the child, but not always.

I created a little visual overview:
[image]

And a video:
https://streamable.com/3x9yxd

In the video you can clearly see that the checkbox state is changing as long as the parent state changes.
Example:

- Parent state is `unchecked`
- Child state is changed to `checked`
- I click `Uncheck` in the parent

Nothing happens.

If the child is untouched it will register a prop change and change the child accordingly.

**Main question:**
How would one be able to pass down a forced state from the parent to a child, but still be able to change the childs checkbox?

Working with watchers? Working with `:key=""` to force a rerender of the childs component (= checkbox)? Working with a nested key `changed="UNIX timestamp"` which can be watched to make sure to detect a change?

Any hints are welcome. Code also but general approaches are absolutely fine.